# Fancybox2 clickable image using captions

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

I would like to make some images clickable to a website in Fancybox2. I copied code from this example: http://jsfiddle.net/w6p49/
It works exactly the way I want except I'm using captions instead of titles. I copied the code from here :http://jsfiddle.net/vkDcG/
My code

```
//Launch website URLS
$("#client-url").click(function() {
    $.fancybox.open([
            {
                href: 'http://xyz.com/images/portfolio/brand/client3/01.jpg',
                link: 'http://www.clientwebsite.com'
            },
            {
                href: 'http://xyz.com/images/portfolio/brand/client3/02.jpg',
                link: 'http://www.clientwebsite.com'
            },
            {
                href: 'http://xyz.com/images/portfolio/brand/client3/03.jpg',
                link: 'http://www.clientwebsite.com'
            },
            {
                href: 'http://xyz.com/images/portfolio/brand/client3/04.jpg',
                link: 'http://www.clientwebsite.com'
            },
        ],
        {
            beforeShow: function() {
                $(".fancybox-image").wrap('<a a target="_blank" href="' + this.link + '" />')
            },
            /*Use caption attribute instead of title*/
            beforeLoad: function () {
                this.title = $(this.element).attr('caption');
            },
            /*Fade image transition instead of default "elastic"*/
            openEffect: 'fade',
            closeEffect: 'fade',
            nextEffect: 'fade',
            prevEffect: 'fade',
            /*Hide the prev button on the first image, and the next button on the last one.*/
           loop: false
        });
    return false;
});
```

Everything works fine except the captions aren't showing. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So do you want the same "caption" (from the clicked thumbnail) for all the images of each gallery set?

Comment: Yes. The captions are the same for each image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having an html like

```
<a id="client-url" caption="This caption will appear in all images of the gallery" href="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/1_b.jpg"><img src="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/1_s.jpg" alt=""/></a>
```

Get the `caption` from the thumbnail link after the `click` event like

```
var caption = $(this).attr("caption");
```

then set the `title` using that variable inside the `beforeShow` callback like

```
this.title = caption;
```

The full code :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#client-url").click(function() {
        var caption = $(this).attr("caption");
        $.fancybox.open([
            {
            href: 'http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/1_b.jpg',
            title: 'this image links to bbc news',
            link: 'http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/'},
        {
            href: 'http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/2_b.jpg',
            title: 'this image links to jquery',
            link: 'http://jquery.com'},
        {
            href: 'http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/3_b.jpg',
            title: 'this image links to fancybox',
            link: 'http://fancyapps.com'}
        ], {
            beforeShow: function() {
                $(".fancybox-image").wrap('<a href="' + this.link + '" />');
                this.title = caption;
            },
            padding: 38,
            nextEffect: 'fade',
            prevEffect: 'fade'
        });
        return false;
    });
}); // ready
```

The **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gqbKF/)**

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra `,` at the end of your links.

```
$.fancybox.open([
    {
        href: 'http://xyz.com/images/portfolio/brand/client3/01.jpg',
        link: 'http://www.clientwebsite.com'
    },
    {
        href: 'http://xyz.com/images/portfolio/brand/client3/02.jpg',
        link: 'http://www.clientwebsite.com'
    },
    {
        href: 'http://xyz.com/images/portfolio/brand/client3/03.jpg',
        link: 'http://www.clientwebsite.com'
    },
    {
        href: 'http://xyz.com/images/portfolio/brand/client3/04.jpg',
        link: 'http://www.clientwebsite.com'
    }, // See here
],
```

That should be like this:

```
$.fancybox.open([
    {
        href: 'http://xyz.com/images/portfolio/brand/client3/01.jpg',
        link: 'http://www.clientwebsite.com'
    },
    {
        href: 'http://xyz.com/images/portfolio/brand/client3/02.jpg',
        link: 'http://www.clientwebsite.com'
    },
    {
        href: 'http://xyz.com/images/portfolio/brand/client3/03.jpg',
        link: 'http://www.clientwebsite.com'
    },
    {
        href: 'http://xyz.com/images/portfolio/brand/client3/04.jpg',
        link: 'http://www.clientwebsite.com'
    } // See here, no coma
],
```

Also there's an extra `a` here:

```
<a a target="_blank" href="' + this.link + '" />
//Should be:
<a target="_blank" href="' + this.link + '" />
```

Comment: You also have an extra `a` here:
`<a a target="_blank" href="' + this.link + '" />`

Comment: geez..thanks again! I made that change as well and still no captions.